# Removing of signals in the same frequency

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I am processing a real audio data which consists of three different signals of the **same frequency**. Those three signals are consisted of 7 beeps and are **different in length and energy level**. (For every signal, the delay between each beep is different)

Signal 1:
[image: Signal 1]

Signal 2:
[image: Signal 2]

Signal 3
[image]

My goal is to filter out every of these signal using the respective matched filter. But the problem is the strength of the signal 1 is too high and I can not apply the other signals matched filter for the data (because the signal 1 will mask the filtering results of other matched filter).

I try to put the process in a loop. After each loop, the filtered signal will be subtracted from the data. But in many cases, the beeps from one signal will be aligned with the beeps of other ones (as in the second picture: the final beep of signal 2 is masked by the stronger beep of another signal).

My questions are:

1. How can I correctly subtract the stronger signals without affecting the weaker ones?
2. After matched filtering, I only got the energy of the signal and matching position. Is there any way to determine the peaks of the beeps from this energy?

Edit:
This is my code to extract the strongest signal:

```
  t_matched = 165428; %matching position
  ct3133 = signal_generator(ones(250,1), fs/25, 380, 640, 460, 640, 400, 640); %generate the "signal 1"
  n = length(ct3133);
  signal_size = length(A222203_30s_d);
  t_begin = t_matched - 3.16*fs/25 -125-5; %position where the signal 1 begin to transmitted
  % 3.16(s) = (380 + 640 + 460 + 640 + 400 + 640)(ms)
  % 25: decimation factor
  % 125: the length of 1 beep (10ms)
  % 5: correction coeffecient due to the dealy between each beep is not ideal.

  %Extracting the signal 1
  signal = cat(1, zeros(t_begin, 1), abs(ct3133), zeros(signal_size - t_begin - n, 1));
  ct3133_sup = abs(ones(length(signal),1)-signal);
  ct3133_extracted = A222203_30s_d.*ct3133_sup;
```

With this method, I was able to remove the Signal 1 from the input data. However, this also removed the last beep of the signal 2 which is masked by the fifth beep of the signal 1.

With the last beep of the signal 2 gone, the signal 2 can be detected by a corresponded matched filter but the matching position is not correct. Therefore, the future operation of removing the signal 2 can not be performed.

Edit 2: 
Here is some graph and data after the extracting of signal 1 operation.

Signal 1 peak and location values:

1. 0.0413 & 125804
2. 0.0411 & 130555
3. 0.0410 & 138555
4. 0.0415 & 144305
5. 0.0417 & 152305
6. 0.0413 & 157306
7. 0.0415 & 165306

Matched filtering result of signal 1 (X: matched position, Y: Signal 1 Energy):

X = 165427, Y = 21.32.
[image: Matched filter result]

Input data after signal 1 is removed:

[image]

Clearly, the signal 2 only contains 6 beeps where it supposes to be 7.

Signal 2 peaks values and locations, respectively:

1. Peak 1: 0.00102 & 110460
2. Peak 2: 0.001114 & 115211
3. Peak 3: 0.001097 & 123211
4. Peak 4: 0.001141 & 128961
5. Peak 5: 0.001139 & 136711
6. Peak 6: 0.001119 & 145462

Result after filtering the above data with the matched filter of signal 2:
[image]

The peak value and location are : 0.3615 & 152383

*The location is the samples, data sampling rate : 12500Hz

Comment: Is it a solution to first extract the stronger signals, remove it from the input signal and extract the lower signals afterwards? Note that a [matched filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter) assumes (or is optimal in the case of) additive stochastic noise, which is not the case here.

Comment: I use matched filter for detecting the signal position and energy. And base on these finds to extract the signals. And my problem is that i cannot extract the stronger signal correctly

Comment: If you know the matching position and the matching filter, you also know the location of the beeps. You can try to simply set the signal at these locations to zero.

Comment: In many cases,  the beeps of the stronger signals mask the weaker ones. What is the solution for this case ?

Comment: In signal 2, you see the beeps of the strong signal do (mostly) not overlap with the beeps of the small signal. So, you can remove the strong beeps from the signal. If a single weak beep is masked by a strong beep, there is probably not so much you can do, but this should not be a problem if it is only the case for one out of the seven beeps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is one in many cases where overlapping occures in more than one beep. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Have you tried it? Even with more than one beep overlap, the matching filter may work. Can you share some code and sample data?

Comment: @m7913d I tried the method but there are some obstacles as stated before. My code and explanation are in the edited part above.

Comment: Yes, matching the strongest beep and then subtracting the estimate should help considerably.

Comment: I expect a matched filter would work with one beep missing, can you provide us a working example including sample data?

Comment: @m7913d yes, it worked, but the problem is the output of the matched filter (location and energy) is not what expected. Also, you can find the examples and data in the edited part above(the second edit)

Comment: What is your expected matched filter peak value location of the second signal? 152383 seems reasonable to me. As it is the case for signal 1, it should give you the location of the (missing) seventh beep.

Comment: The delays for signal 2 are: 380, 640, 460, 620, 700, 560. With fs = 12500Hz, the delay between the sixth and seventh signal must be at least: 0.56*12500=7000 (samples). Therefore, the position of the last beep must be equal or larger: 145462+7000=152462. The position found in the match filtering result is inappropriate. I need the location of signal to be accurate because it will be used for the localization procedure later.

Comment: Two ideas you can try: after the first course match, (1) remove the missing beeps from your matched filter and try to localise the signal again or (2) correct the course estimation based on the detection of the maximum of the different beeps.